# @rpath for a dynamic library embedded in a framework

Tags: macos, dynamic-linking, rpath

I have an app, call it `Animal.app`.  Inside its `Contents/Frameworks` folder is a framework, say `Mammal.framework`.  And inside the `Versions/A/Frameworks` folder of the framework, I have `dog.dylib`.  The install name of `dog.dylib` is @rpath/dog.dylib.  For the `"Runpath Search Paths"` setting of the framework, I have specified `@loader_path/../Frameworks`.  (My reasoning for that last setting is that the "loader" of the dylib would be the binary of the framework, at the path `Mammal.framework/Versions/A/Mammal`.)

I get an error message at runtime:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/dog.dylib
  Referenced from: /Volumes/VOLUME/*/Animal.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Mammal.framework/Versions/A/Mammal
  Reason: image not found
```

I've read Apple's "Run-Path Dependent Libraries" documentation, and Mike Ash's blog post on `@rpath`, but I still can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that the right runpath search path is `@loader_path/Frameworks`.  What I was missing is that @loader_path represents, not the full path to the loader, but that path minus its last component.  [Mike Ash's blog post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html) does say that, but I somehow missed it.  Thus, in the case of a framework, @loader_path ends with the A.

Comment: Yes, to be clear: the Installation Directory for both your nested dylib and its parent framework should be "@rpath". The parent framework then includes "@loader_path/Frameworks" in its Runpath Search Paths (since the dylib ends up as a sibling of the Frameworks folder); the app using this framework includes "@loader_path/../Frameworks" (since the executable is down in MacOS). The app could use `@executable_path` just as well, but `@loader_path` seems cooler :-)

Comment: I don't understand what you actually did to make it work... explain it to me like I'm 6.

Comment: @Prof.Falken:  In the build settings for the framework, under Linking, there is a setting called "Runpath Search Paths".  I set its value to `@loader_path/Frameworks`.